# State of the Art versions of Generalized Additive Models

Tags: r, machine-learning, python, generalized-additive-model, mars

[Generalized Additive Models [Trevor Hastie and Robert Tibshirani 86]](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ss/1177013604) was well received with over 1335 Citations.

I am also aware of the popular(?) version of GAM - the Multivariate Adaptive Regression Splines [MARS by Friedman 91 - 4568 Citations](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aos/1176347963).

I would like to know how popular / scalable / practically valid, the sparse version of GAM - the Sparse Additive Model ( SpAM ) is in comparison to the MARS. I am planning to implement this for academic purposes. Would it be worth the effort spent in learning about this assuming I am trying to learn more about GAMs in general or should I choose any other state of the art GAM model which is widely accepted ( Other than MARS ) to implement and learn?

It would be awesome if you could keep in mind that I am a newbie to this field.

Also I am new to this community please let me know if this question is considered on topic too.

References for SpAM:

- [NIPS - Han Liu, Pradeep Ravikumar et al - 07 - 238 Citations](http://repository.cmu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2030&context=compsci)
- Sparse Additive Machine - JMLR - T. Zhao 12
- [Yahoo AAAI 15](http://labs.yahoo.com/publication/causal-inference-via-sparse-additive-models-with-application-to-online-advertising/).

Also closely related - [Generalized additive models -- who does research on them besides Simon Wood?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/122426/61772)

**EDIT:**

To summarize these are the 3 questions I'd love an answer for -

- With just academic interest and no particular application in mind, what is the state of the art research in GAMs?
- How popular / scalable / practically valid is the sparse version SpAM?
- I'd like to learn about GAMs and implement a GAM based model that is widely accepted ( like MARS ) preferably in Python ( MARS already has PyEarth ). Which one would you recommend and why?

Comment: The paper you are presumably alluding to is by Trevor Hastie and Robert Tibshirani in _Statistical Science_. You omitted the first author and misspelled the name of the second. (Anyone answering this question would know that, but it's put in for some others.)

Comment: I suggest that you are posing three very different questions. The first alone calls for a review paper. Are new implementations needed? (Whether MARS is a "popular version" of GAM I leave to experts.) You are posting as a newbie aiming to offer an implementation for researchers; that is impressively ambitious.

Comment: "The ... others." -  Thanks! Have edited the same :) ; "You are posting as a newbie aiming to offer an implementation for researchers;" - Ah! nope ;) Like I said I'd like to "to implement and learn". The reason I was looking for a good one to implement is so that I don't expend my energy in a wrong direction :)

Comment: I like your thoughtful questions but it will be closed as too broad. Divide the three questions into separate questions and it will help to make them more precise.